# readline package rpm installation fails when tries using system() API

Tags: c, rpm, readline, glibc, rpmbuild

When trying rpm installing via CLI/shell prompt, the files are getting installed without issues.

```
/bin/rpm -ivU --nodeps --force --root /mnt /tmp/readline-4.2-4.ppc.rpm
```

When we try the same via `system()` API, it throws the below error.

```
ret = system("/bin/rpm -ivU --nodeps --force --root /tmp/rpm /tmp/readline-4.2-4.ppc.rpm");
printf("ret = %d\n", ret);
```

**ERROR FROM CONSOLE**

```
Preparing packages for installation...

readline-4.2-4
/bin/sh: error while loading shared libraries: libreadline.so.4.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

error: execution of %post scriptlet from readline-4.2-4 failed, exit status 127
ret = 256

We have also tried debugging using strace. Please find the strace logs.

write(38, "sfile=/etc/ld.so.conf\nif ! grep "..., 116) = 116

close(38)                               = 0

munmap(0x37f4d000, 8192)                = 0

dup(1)                                  = 38

clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x37f48068) = 23955

waitpid(23955, /bin/sh: error while loading shared libraries: 
libreadline.so.4.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 127}], 0) = 23955

--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=23955, si_status=127, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
```

Could someone please help us here ?

Comment: some path may not be setup properly because it's not a login or interactive shell ... what happens if you do `sh -c "your command"` in a terminal ?

Comment: It may have something to do with the `--root /tmp/rpm` option.

Comment: The issue is not related to readline rpm here. We found an issue in the rpm's post install script. Thank you for response